# Getting number of newlines and storing each in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, networking, interface, wifi

I am making a script that will let you choose between which interface you want to use.

I need a way to get the interfaces and store each of them in a variable.

Here is my code, but it only gets the interfaces:

```
Interfaces=$(ifconfig | awk '{print $1}' | grep ':' | tr -d ':')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to only check the lines that contain the interface name, not the lines with details. In `ifconfig`, detail lines start with a space; in `ip`, interface lines start with a number.

In bash, you can use `select` to create a simple menu:

```
#! /bin/bash
select interface in $(ip link show | grep '^[0-9]' | cut -f2 -d:) ; do
    if [[ $interface ]] ; then
        echo You selected $interface
        break
    fi
done
```

or

```
select interface in $(ifconfig -a | grep -v '^ ' | cut -f1 -d' ') ; do
    if [[ $interface ]] ; then
        echo You selected $interface
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed :D

Comment: But, is there anyway to change the "#?" prompt?

Comment: @MaliciouZzHD: Of course, just set `PS3='Select an interface: '`.

Comment: Thanks, I was just learning how to change the bash prompt with PS1